# PrimeFaces - Don't close dialog when messages appears

Tags: validation, primefaces

How can I set up a Primefaces Dialog to not hide, when there are "required-messages" open? At this moment, the dialog will closing by clicking on the "Speichern" Button, and when reopened, the messages appears... I would like to let the dialog open, when there are unfilled required fields:

```xml
<h:panelGrid id="createNewPat" columns="3" cellpadding="1" style="margin:0 auto;">  
    <h:outputText for="versNr" value="Versicherten-Nr.:" />  
    <p:inputMask id="versNr" value="#{patientenBean.versNr}" required="true"/>  
    <p:message for="versNr" />
    <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Speichern" 
         action="#{patientenBean.createPatient}" 
         oncomplete="if (!args.messageOccured) createNewPat.hide();" 
         update="patForm" />
    <p:commandButton id="resetBtn" value="Reset" type="reset" /> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: oncomplete="(args.messageOccured)? createNewPat.show(): createNewPat.hide(); "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the dialog to not close, your `commandButton` (or any component that updates the dialog's container) has to update inside the dialog. Do not update the dialog's container, for example:

```xml
<p:dialog id="dlg">
    <p:panel id="pntest">
        // content here
        <p:commandButton update=":#{p:component('pntest')}"/>
    </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

if not, you have to open the dialog again in `oncomplete`:

```
oncomplete="(args.messageOccured)? createNewPat.show(): createNewPat.hide(); "
```

Comment: Yes, see my answer... found an other way. It was simple, but a bit hard to find out...

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on an my exame this weeks... much to learn, hehe... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Solved the Problem yesterday (after 3 hours googling and testing) like this:

```
<p:dialog header="Patient erfassen" widgetVar="createNewPat" 
        resizable="true" id="createPatDlg" >  
        <h:form id="dlgErf">

            <h:panelGrid id="createNewPat" columns="3" cellpadding="1" 
                style="margin:0 auto;">  

                <h:outputText for="versNr" value="Versicherten-Nr.:" />  
                <p:inputMask id="versNr" value="#{patientenBean.versNr}"
                  required="true" >
                    <!--    <f:validateLength minimum="2" /> -->
                </p:inputMask>
                <p:message for="versNr" />
```

Here are the Buttons:

```
    <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Speichern" 
   action="#{patientenBean.createPatient}" 
   oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){createNewPat.hide()}"
       update="createNewPat"/>

<p:commandButton id="resetBtn" value="Reset" process="@this" update="createNewPat" 
        action="#{patientenBean.reset}">
      <p:resetInput target="createNewPat" />
</p:commandButton> 

  </h:panelGrid>
```

And the Reset Button now works too - Method in Bean is simply for setting all the attributes to NULL:

```
public void reset() {
    logger.info("Reset-Methode: Leeren der Felder!");
    versNr=null;
    name=null;
    vorname=null;
    strasseNr=null;
    plz=null;
    ort=null;
    geschlecht=null;
    geburtsdatum=null;

    versNrEdit=null;
    nameEdit=null;
    vornameEdit=null;
    strasseNrEdit=null;
    plzEdit=null;
    ortEdit=null;
    geschlechtEdit=null;
    geburtsdatumEdit=null;

}
```

Thanx for your help!